# Why is my divs rendering wrong by not aligning

Tags: html, css

I can not figure out why it is doing this

here is the css

```
.logo{
position:relative;
height:200px;
width:200px;
border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
float:left;
padding:0px;

}

.feed{
position:absolute;
height:200px;
width: 100%;
border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
overflow: auto;
white-space:nowrap;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;

}


.feed-box {
position:relative;
width: 550px;
height: 200px;
display:inline-block;
border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
white-space:normal;
top:10px;


}
```

here is the html

```
<body>

<div class="feed">

        <div class="feed-box"  >

        </div>

        <div class="feed-box"  >
          grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe
        </div>

        <div class="feed-box"  >
          grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe
        </div>

        <div class="feed-box"  >
          grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe
        </div>

        <div class="feed-box"  >
          grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe
        </div>



</div>




</body>
```

I dont know how to explain this so here is a link

http://jsfiddle.net/G5YZ6/300/

whys is it that the divs are not aligning but are going down. What I want is some thing like this

```
<body>

<div class="feed">

        <div class="feed-box"  >
                      grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe
        </div>

        <div class="feed-box"  >
          grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe
        </div>

        <div class="feed-box"  >
          grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe
        </div>

        <div class="feed-box"  >
          grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe
        </div>

        <div class="feed-box"  >
          grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe grefewfgewfgewgwe
        </div>



</div>




</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G5YZ6/301/

but some reason the if i do not have the same amount of text it all goes wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `vertical-align:top` to `.feed-box`:

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/G5YZ6/302/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `whitespace: normal;` from `.feed-box{}` in your CSS. It's unnecessary and doing some weird things to your code. Replace it `overflow: auto;`

Comment: the reason I put it in is that the text was not wrapping in the div. I want the divs feed-box to scroll to the right but the only way I know how to do that is white-space:nowrap; but it is causing the text to not wrap too

Comment: @Mental-State I've updated my answer to handle what you want.